# powercfg gives invalid parameter error

Tags: command-line, powercfg

I am trying to run powercfg according to these site: http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html

To be exact I want to run this command via .batch file

```
Set _Custom_Power=B1234567-SS64-SS64-SS64-F00000111AAA
Powercfg -DUPLICATESCHEME SCHEME_MAX %_Custom_Power%
Powercfg -CHANGENAME %_Custom_Power% "SS64 Power Scheme "
Powercfg -SETACTIVE %_Custom_Power%
```

but it does not work and when I try to run it via cmd I get an

> Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help

I found out that when I leave %_Custom__Power% out and let powercfg auto-generate a guid this error does not happen.

What could be the problem ??

Comment: If you do `Powercfg -list` is `B1234567-SS64-SS64-SS64-F00000111AAA` listed?  Why don't you duplicate the schema, use that guid, instead of the example guid

Comment: It would be easier just to use the GUID value itself in a case like this.  `Powercfg -DUPLICATESCHEME SCHEME_MAX B1234567-SS64-SS64-SS64-F00000111AAA` worked without a problem for me

Comment: I tried that and I get the same error when entering the GUID value itself

Comment: What version of powershell?

Comment: powershell? I am using CMD for that but I tried with powershell too. Same error unfortunately. My pc is on windows 8.1

Comment: Follow @Ramhound - but instead suggested `-list` option use `-aliases` one to display all aliases and their corresponding GUIDs: `powercfg -aliases`